# Dealing with non-uniform JSON columns in spark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to know what is the best practice for reading a newline delimited JSON file into a dataframe. Critically, one of the (required) fields in each record maps to an object that is not guaranteed to have the same sub-fields (ie the schema is non-uniform across all the records).

For example, an input file might look like:

```
{"id": 1, "type": "foo", "data": {"key0": "foo", "key2": "meh"}}
{"id": 2, "type": "bar", "data": {"key2": "poo", "key3": "pants"}}
{"id": 3, "type": "baz", "data": {"key3": "moo"}}
```

In this case the fields `id`, `type`, and `data` will be present in all records, but the struct mapped to by `data` will have a heterogeneous schema.

I have two approaches for dealing with the non-uniformity of the `data` column:

1. let Spark infer the schema:

```
df = spark.read.options(samplingRatio=1.0).json('s3://bucket/path/to/newline_separated_json.txt')
```

The obvious issue with this approach is the need to sample *every* record to determine the super-set of fields/schemas that will be the final schema. This may be prohibitively expensive given a dataset in the low 100s of millions of records? Or...

2. Tell Spark to coerce the data field into a JSON string, and then just have a schema comprised of three top-level string fields, `id`, `type`, `data`. And here I'm not really sure the best way to proceed. For example I am assuming just declaring the `data` field to be a string as in the following, will not work because it is not explicitly doing the equivalent of `json.dumps`?

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), true),
    StructField("type", StringType(), true),
    StructField("data", StringType(), true)
])
df = spark.read.json('s3://bucket/path/to/newline_separated_json.txt', schema=schema)
```

If I want to avoid the cost of scanning the full dataset incurred by option 1, what is the best way to ingest this file and keep the `data` field as a JSON string?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your attempt and the overall idea is in the right direction. Here are two more approaches based on the build-in options aka `get_json_object`/`from_json` via dataframe API and using `map` transformation along with python's `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` via the RDD API.

**Option 1:** **get_json_object()** / **from_json()**

First let's try with `get_json_object()` which doesn't require a schema:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('{"id": 1, "type": "foo", "data": {"key0": "foo", "key2": "meh"}}'),
  ('{"id": 2, "type": "bar", "data": {"key2": "poo", "key3": "pants"}}'),
  ('{"id": 3, "type": "baz", "data": {"key3": "moo"}}')
], StringType())

df.select(f.get_json_object("value", "$.id").alias("id"), \
          f.get_json_object("value", "$.type").alias("type"), \
           f.get_json_object("value", "$.data").alias("data"))

# +---+----+-----------------------------+
# |id |type|data                         |
# +---+----+-----------------------------+
# |1  |foo |{"key0":"foo","key2":"meh"}  |
# |2  |bar |{"key2":"poo","key3":"pants"}|
# |3  |baz |{"key3":"moo"}               |
# +---+----+-----------------------------+
```

On the contrary `from_json()` requires a schema definition:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('{"id": 1, "type": "foo", "data": {"key0": "foo", "key2": "meh"}}'),
  ('{"id": 2, "type": "bar", "data": {"key2": "poo", "key3": "pants"}}'),
  ('{"id": 3, "type": "baz", "data": {"key3": "moo"}}')
], StringType())

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("data", StringType(), True)
])

df.select(f.from_json("value", schema).getItem("id").alias("id"), \
         f.from_json("value", schema).getItem("type").alias("type"), \
         f.from_json("value", schema).getItem("data").alias("data"))

# +---+----+-----------------------------+
# |id |type|data                         |
# +---+----+-----------------------------+
# |1  |foo |{"key0":"foo","key2":"meh"}  |
# |2  |bar |{"key2":"poo","key3":"pants"}|
# |3  |baz |{"key3":"moo"}               |
# +---+----+-----------------------------+
```

**Option 2: map/RDD API + json.dumps()**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
import json

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  '{"id": 1, "type": "foo", "data": {"key0": "foo", "key2": "meh"}}',
  '{"id": 2, "type": "bar", "data": {"key2": "poo", "key3": "pants"}}',
  '{"id": 3, "type": "baz", "data": {"key3": "moo"}}'
], StringType())

def from_json(data):
  row = json.loads(data[0])
  return (row['id'], row['type'], json.dumps(row['data']))

json_rdd = df.rdd.map(from_json)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("data", StringType(), True)
])

spark.createDataFrame(json_rdd, schema).show(10, False)

# +---+----+--------------------------------+
# |id |type|data                            |
# +---+----+--------------------------------+
# |1  |foo |{"key2": "meh", "key0": "foo"}  |
# |2  |bar |{"key2": "poo", "key3": "pants"}|
# |3  |baz |{"key3": "moo"}                 |
# +---+----+--------------------------------+
```

Function `from_json` will transform the string row into a tuple of `(id, type, data)`. [json.loads()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) will parse the json string and return a dictionary through which we generate and return the final tuple.

Comment: This looks promising, I guess there's still the overhead of running map on the rdd, but potentially that's cheaper than checking every record for the schema in the samplingRatio=1.0 case. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that is true, since map is a narrow transformation it shouldn't cause an overhead at all

Comment: Hi @WhitneyZoller I updated the answer by adding one more option using either `get_json_object` (when you dont know the schema) or `from_json`

Comment: I believe that there shoudn't be any important difference between the two approaches since in both cases the json row need to be parsed

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [Rumble](http://rumbledb.org) to query, on Spark, heterogeneous JSON datasets that do not fit in DataFrames. This is precisely the problem it solves. It is free and open-source.

For example:

```
for $i in json-file("s3://bucket/path/to/newline_separated_json.txt")
where keys($i.data) = "key2" (: keeping only those objects that have a key2 :)
group by $type := $i.type
return {
  "type" : $type,
  "key2-values" : [ $i.data.key2 ]
}
```

(Disclaimer: I am part of the team.)