# Convert a dataframe column with json string into different columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting data from a blob location into a dataframe as below.

```
| NUM_ID|                                                                                                                              Event|
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599398000,"V":19.79},{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599406000,"V":19.80},{"SN":"SIG2","E":1571599406000,"V":25.30},{...|
|XXXXX02|[{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599414000,"V":19.79},{"SN":"SIG2","E":1571599414000,"V":19.80},{"SN":"SIG2","E":1571599424000,"V":25.30},{...|
```

If we take a single row it will be as below.

```
|XXXXX01|[{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599398000,"V":19.79},{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599406000,"V":19.80},{"SN":"SIG1","E":1571599414000,"V":19.20},{"SN":"SIG2","E":1571599424000,"V":25.30},{"SN":"SIG2","E":1571599432000,"V":19.10},{"SN":"SIG3","E":1571599440000,"V":19.10},{"SN":"SIG3","E":1571599448000,"V":19.10},{"SN":"SIG3","E":1571599456000,"V":19.10},{"SN":"SIG3","E":1571599396000,"V":19.79},{"SN":"SIG3","E":1571599404000,"V":19.79}]
```

Event column is having different signals as E,V pair.

The schema for this dataframe is as shown below.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- NUM_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Event: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to take some signals(suppose i need only SIG1 and SIG3) along with E,V pairs as a new column as shown below.

```
+-------+--------+--------------+------+
| NUM_ID|   Event|             E|     V|
+-------+--------+--------------+------+
|XXXXX01|    SIG1| 1571599398000| 19.79|
|XXXXX01|    SIG1| 1571599406000| 19.80|
|XXXXX01|    SIG1| 1571599414000| 19.20|
|XXXXX01|    SIG3| 1571599440000| 19.10|
|XXXXX01|    SIG3| 1571599448000| 19.10|
|XXXXX01|    SIG3| 1571599406000| 19.10|
|XXXXX01|    SIG3| 1571599396000| 19.70|
|XXXXX01|    SIG3| 1571599404000| 19.70|
+-------+--------+--------------+------+
```

and the final output should be as like below for each **NUM_ID**.

```
+-------+--------------+------+------+
| NUM_ID|             E|SIG1 V|SIG3 V|    
+-------+--------------+------+------+
|XXXXX01| 1571599398000| 19.79|  null|
|XXXXX01| 1571599406000| 19.80| 19.70|
|XXXXX01| 1571599414000| 19.20|  null|
|XXXXX01| 1571599440000|  null| 19.10|
|XXXXX01| 1571599448000|  null| 19.10|
|XXXXX01| 1571599448000|  null| 19.10|
|XXXXX01| 1571599406000| 19.80| 19.10|
|XXXXX01| 1571599396000|  null| 19.70|
|XXXXX01| 1571599404000|  null| 19.70|
+-------+--------------+------+------+
```

Appreciate any leads.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala- I tried to convert the Event column into struct type as below.
```val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField("SN", StringType), StructField("E", StringType), StructField("V", StringType))))```

```df.withColumn("sig_array", from_json($"Event", schema))```
And obtaining [SN, E, V ] as a new column, now trying to explode that column!

Comment: You could also use `from_json` if json has a predefined schema or `get_json_object` if you dont know the schema as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171816/dealing-with-non-uniform-json-columns-in-spark-dataframe/58180779#58180779)

Answer (score 1):

Above Event column contains multiple records in a row, that is data has to flatten before processing it further. Data flattening could be achieved by a flatmap transformation operation on DataFrame.

The approach is creating a flatten JSON Dataframe having all the necessary key & values in it, and finally JSON to DataFrame conversion via Spark read json API.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
import spark.implicits._

val flatDF = df.flatMap(row => {
  val numId = row.getAs[String]("NUM_ID")
  val event = row.getAs[String]("Event")
  val data = mapper.readValue(event, classOf[Array[java.util.Map[String, String]]])

  data.map(jsonMap => {
    jsonMap.put("NUM_ID", numId)
    mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap)
  })
})

val finalDF = spark.read.json(flatDF)

//finalDF Outout
+-------------+-------+----+-----+
|            E| NUM_ID|  SN|    V|
+-------------+-------+----+-----+
|1571599398000|XXXXX01|SIG1|19.79|
|1571599406000|XXXXX01|SIG1| 19.8|
|1571599406000|XXXXX01|SIG2| 25.3|
|1571599414000|XXXXX02|SIG1|19.79|
|1571599414000|XXXXX02|SIG2| 19.8|
|1571599424000|XXXXX02|SIG2| 25.3|
+-------------+-------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obtained by getting json object and exploding the column as below.

```
val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField("SN", StringType), StructField("E", StringType), StructField("V", StringType))))
val structDF = fromBlobDF.withColumn("sig_array", from_json($"Event", schema))

val signalsDF = structDF.withColumn("sig_array", explode($"sig_array")).withColumn("SIGNAL", $"sig_array.SN").withColumn("E", $"sig_array.E").withColumn("V", $"sig_array.V").select("NUM_ID","E","SIGNAL","V")
```