# PySpark - StructType can not accept object 'string indices must be integers' in type <class 'str'> PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

When trying to access the json in string format inside map function, throwing TypeError

TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'string indices must be integers' in type <class 'str'>

I tried many posts on Stackoverflow, like [Dealing with non-uniform JSON columns in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171816/dealing-with-non-uniform-json-columns-in-spark-dataframe)
Non of it worked.

Basically , when the json response string is accessed, it throwing the Exception.

```
Input JSON records
{
  "testPolicy": "personal",
  "testPolicyVersion": "00",
  "creditModel": "",
  "personalRequest": {
    "testContract": {
      "requestType": "PRE-SCREEN",
      "transactionDateTimeStamp": "2020-11-24:T08:53:27",
      "transactionID": "e04bef99-37d8-4a2b-a588-b6d019ecb157",
      "testData": [
        {
          "DataHeaders": "a|b|c",
          "DataValues": "1|2|3",
          "Bureau": "TEST"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load("s3://bucket/response-pass1.csv")
df.show(1)
df.printSchema()


testresponse = StructType([
    StructField('scoreVal', StringType(), True)

])

def processTestScore(row):
    odp_policy_res = row.json_response
    vals = ""
    try:
        if(odp_policy_res != "HTTP error500" ):
            resp = json.loads(odp_policy_res)
            vals = odp_policy_res['personalRequest']['testContract']['testData'][0]['DataValues']
        else:
            vals = odp_policy_res
    except Exception as e:
        vals = str(e)
    return Row(vals)
    

rdd_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda x : processTestScore(x))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=rdd_1, schema = test_response )
df2.show()



This is throwing exceptions as below, 


+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|    json_request|   json__response|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|fcc5487a-ad24-49d...|{"testPolicy": ...|{"testPolicy": ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- json_request: string (nullable = true)
 |-- json_response: string (nullable = true)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87644.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 662.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 662.0 (TID 21480, 10.87.12.222, executor 17): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 730, in prepare
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1389, in verify
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1377, in verify_struct
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'string indices must be integers' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1477)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2191)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2190)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1058)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1058)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1058)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2358)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2379)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2548)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2548)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2548)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 730, in prepare
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1389, in verify
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1377, in verify_struct
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'string indices must be integers' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake of accessing string values[assuming it as dict, as I converted it in the before statement]

I has to be

```
 resp = json.loads(odp_policy_res)
 vals = resp['personalRequest']['testContract']['testData'][0]['DataValues']
```

Instead of

```
resp = json.loads(odp_policy_res)
vals = odp_policy_res['personalRequest']['testContract']['testData'][0]['DataValues']
```

That solved the issue.

```
def processTestScore(row):
    odp_policy_res = row.json_response
    vals = ""
    try:
        if(odp_policy_res != "HTTP error500" ):
            resp = json.loads(odp_policy_res)
            vals = resp['personalRequest']['testContract']['testData'][0]['DataValues']
        else:
            vals = odp_policy_res
    except Exception as e:
        vals = str(e)
    return Row(vals)
```